# how to avoid being a point of reference for functional and technical issues without getting a financial reward?

Tags: software-industry, salary

It is quite a long time now that in my company I am a point of reference both for functional and technical problems, I mean that I sometimes work as a business analyst as to say I get the customer question and translate it in a solution, sometimes I work as an It architect.

My role by the way is neither of these two but I should be only a software developer or engineer.
In my company there are others who are entitled for functional analisys or for software architect, and obviously they are getting more money than me.

Sometimes I have been asked this because one is missing, or because one tries to avoid work, or because one tries not to get a responsability, or because he knows I will be the next and knows I'll accept to solve

Now I am bouncing back the emails I get if I understand someone should solve it... but I mean I want to solve it different, I want my company to recognize my value and I want an up shift in my salary.

Would it be a good strategy to underline all these reasons to my current manager ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sounds like standard responsibilities of a non-junior developer/engineer, sharing expertise to improve the skills of the group as a whole. Refusing to do so could have career limiting consequences and have *negative* impact on your salary.

Talk to your manager -- non-confrontationally! -- about how to prioritize these requests relative to your other work. I think you will find that at least some of this is required if you want to continue to advance in the company. But there may be ways to limit how much of a distraction it becomes, eg by having requests come through your manager so they can be filtered/prioritized properly.

And remember that in most cases you get a promotion only after proving you can work at that level.

Answer (score 0):

> Would it be a good strategy to underline all these reasons to my current manager ?

Of course it would be a good strategy to talk about that with your direct manager. If he or she does not know, he cannot do anything to improve the situation. Tell them that you do more things than noted in your job description. And tell them that you like your additional tasks. You should definetly raise the visibility of that.

If your manager does not get the hint, you can be proactive and ask them directly about the possibility to change your job description (and compensation, of course). After that it is in his hand and they will tell you yes or no (hopefully).

Answer (score 0):

You need your manager to set some guidelines for what your responsibilities are. Second, if you find these requests are outside of what your manager expects, ask the manager what you should do if you get these requests. Have examples ready if he is not sure what you mean.

You may discover this is your job or you need to be denying these requests. Other people may become advocates for you if you're as good as you say you are. If that is the case, it may lead to a promotion.

Don't go to your boss and ask for a raise because you're doing all this work he doesn't think you should be doing. Know what is expected of you and then when you can show you exceed it, use that as a basis when asking for a raise.